# Creating variants

Tags: field, variants

I need to create variants for my entries ( the entry type is `Product` but I'm not on Craft Commerce ).

The variants have a number of features. Those features may change between products ( ex. variants of a product have the feature 'pressure' while others doesn't ).

I have two ideas, each with pro and cons, I would like to know if anyone else ever solved a similar situation in a smarter way.

1. Use a Matrix of Super tables, where each block represents a variant and each "column" of a block can be active or not.
2. Create an entry type for variants, then associate those variants to product via an entry field type.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be an option to create the `section` products with the different entry types instead of creating an entry type `products`? Also it would make more sense to create a section `variants` and not an entry type because you would not be able to create different variants that way

Comment: Uhm, these could address the heterogeneity of the features but will add a more complex structure for very similar entries ( apart from the variants field ).

I was hoping to keep the entries structure more simple but I'll think about that. Thanks